# How to represent multiple elements of the same set correctly?

Tags: modeling

In a mathematical model, I have a set $J$ of distinct jobs, and a constraint dealing with pairs of elements from the job set. Which of the following is the most accurate way to address two jobs $j$ and $j'$ from the set $J$?

1. $j,j' \in J$
2. $(j,j') \in J$
3. $j,j' \in J^2$
4. $(j,j') \in J^2$

In short, I want to know whether I need brackets, and the set should be $J$, or $J^2$?

** Perhaps a basic question, but I want to be accurate in my writing.

Comment: From the perspective of a guy who have little experience in math, 1. is the easiest to understand (and 5. of Rob Pratt answer if you want to be more correct).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitely not 2 or 3.  1 is often used but a little informal.  4 is most accurate.
Two more suggestions:

5. $j\in J,\ j'\in J$
6. $(j,j')\in J\times J$